# How do I reorder open tabs?

Tags: multiple-files, tabbed-user-interface

Let's say I have four open files: `file0.txt`, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`. I open all of them in that order as tabs. So my tab ordering is this:

- `file0.txt`
- `file1.txt`
- `file2.txt`
- `file3.txt`

Then let's say that I want to instead reorder my tabs so that `file2.txt` comes before `file1.txt`:

- `file0.txt`
- `file2.txt`
- `file1.txt`
- `file3.txt`

How do I do that? Is there a Vim command to move the current tab to the left or right, or otherwise reorder the currently opened tabs?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `tabmove` command. (`:help tabmove` will tell you all you need to know)

The command takes two kind of parameters:

A sign (`+` or `-`) followed by a number:

- `:tabmove +2` will move your tab of 2 places to the right
- `:tabmove -2` will do the same to the left.

You can also use the command with a simple number to set the position of the tab:

- `:tabmove 0` will put the tab as the first one
- `:tabmove 2` will put the tab in the third position
- `:tabmove` will put the tab as the last one

Also I put those lines in my `.vimrc`

```
" move current tab to left/right
noremap <Leader><Left>  :execute 'silent! tabmove ' . (tabpagenr()-2)<CR>
noremap <Leader><Right> :execute 'silent! tabmove ' . tabpagenr()<CR>
```

They allow you to move the current tab of one place with the combination <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> maybe they could be useful to you.

**Edit:** As @TomMcDo pointed out in the comments the previous mappings could be simplified and still work properly:

```
noremap <Leader><Left>  :tabmove -1<CR>
noremap <Leader><Right> :tabmove +1<CR>
```

Comment: In your mappings, why not use `:tabmove -1` and `:tabmove +1`?

Comment: @tommcdo: Well... I made those mappings several months ago and I have no idea of what was in my mind at this moment. And I didn't event gave a thought about it when I copied it in my answer. Anyway you're totally right I'll edit my answer to make is simpler thanks for the heading :-)